# Regex /g - global search flag not count ending tag as next starting tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a line of text which is like:

```
    Hi %this% is the %text% I was talking about.
```

I want to replace `%this%` and `%text%` with some other text. I am using this regex:

```
str.replace(/(%)(.*)(%)/g, "something")
```

But this replaces **three** strings `%this%`, `%text%` and also `% is the %`. Is there any flag to let `/g` start afresh after the `%` ending tag and not count it as the next starting tag ?

Comment: Regexp has nothing to do with jQuery, it's just regular Javascript

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around the parts of the regular expression? You're not doing anything with the capture groups.

Comment: I am using it in the actual implementation $2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that `.*` is too greedy in your regex.

You can use negation:

```
var r = str.replace(/%[^%]*%/g, "something");
//=> Hi something is the something I was talking about
```

Or else just match a word between `%`:

```
var r = str.replace(/%\w*%/g, "something");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
> '    Hi %this% is the %text% I was talking about.'.replace(/%.*?%/g, "something")
'    Hi something is the something I was talking about.'
```

**Explanation:**

- `%` Matches a literal `%`
- `.*?%` Matches upto the next `%` . `?` after `*` force the regex engine to do a shortest match.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
str.replace(/%[^%]*%/g, "something")
```